# How to create an incremental index number that does not change if other rows are deleted?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

It is easy to create an index number in Power Query, but the issue is, if records in the source dataset are removed, all the index numbers change. I need to create index numbers for each row in my source data that won't change even if other records are deleted. I'm exploring ways to do this in VBA and Power Query.

EDIT:

I didn't realize it would be helpful to see example tables, so here they are.

Here is a table:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

And we are adding an index column to that table in a query using power query, for example:

| A header | Another header | An index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | 0 |
| Second | row | 1 |

And then when we remove a row from the source dataset and refresh our query, the index row numbers are modified:

| A header | Another header | An index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Second | row | 0 |

What I want is to keep the index numbers assigned to rows, even if rows are deleted, so the data would look like this:

| A header | Another header | An index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Second | row | 1 |

Comment: Not enough details - where is your data and how are records added/deleted?  Is there currently an empty index column or ?  What exactly is the "source dataset", etc.

Comment: You can do this in VBA by storing the current index number in (eg) a cell or a worksheet name: loop over each new record, add the index number and increment the number in the cell/name.  You can only do this in one place though: if you have >1 process adding records you need to find a way to have a shared index.

Comment: Could you provide some example code to do that? This seems to be what I need

Comment: @TimWilliams btw deleted my other question because I realized that fundamentally the issue is creating these unique record IDs, not appending the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")
    
    'populate index in any empty cell in ColA
    For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
            c.Value = NextIndex
        End If
    Next c
End Sub


'return index value and increment: use a cell
Function NextIndex() As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index").Range("A1")
        NextIndex = .Value
        .Value = NextIndex + 1
    End With
End Function

'return index value and increment: use a workbook Name
Function NextIndexName() As Long
    Const INDEX_NM As String = "myIndex"
    Dim nm As Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set nm = ThisWorkbook.Names(INDEX_NM)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If nm Is Nothing Then
        Set nm = ThisWorkbook.Names.Add(Name:=INDEX_NM, RefersTo:=1)
    End If
    With nm
        NextIndexName = CLng(Evaluate(.RefersTo))
        .RefersTo = NextIndexName + 1
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: this is nearly perfect. do I need to store the index numbers in another sheet or is there way to store the index numbers in some sort of internal counter?

Comment: Added a version which uses a workbook Name instead of a cell....

Comment: Hi Tim -- is it possible to use something like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619200/creating-a-counter-in-vba ... I'm trying to play around with this to adapt it to your script (so that the counter does not have to be stored in a sheet or sheet name etc) but I'm not very strong with VBA so I don't even know if using a counter like this is compatible with the function you wrote

Comment: also to improve my understanding of the script -- what does the period (.) in .Value mean? and in For each c in ws.Range, does c refer to a cell? so c.Value refers to the cell's value? thank you in advance for your help

Comment: When using a `With [someobject]` block, the leading period scopes the method/property to [someobject].    And `For each c in ws.Range` is short for `For each c in ws.Range.Cells` so Yes `c` is a cell.

Comment: Your linked post would not be applicable here - you can't persist a VBA variable across sessions.  That's why you need to store the value in a cell/Name/file etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not.  You need a (unique) key column, not an index. Perhaps by

concatenating other columns

```
=[column1]&[column2]&[column3]
```

or using a multicolumn hash such as

```
=Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.ToList(Text.Combine({[Column1],[Column2],[Column3]})), each Text.From(Character.ToNumber(_))))
```

or

```
= Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary(Text.Combine({[Column1],[Column2],[Column3]})))
```

Comment: unfortunately I already have a column which concatenates information to create a unique key column, but the issue is , that unique key column risks being modified if values are modified in the columns used to create the key. so I really need an ID/index/unique key that is created incrementally and which cannot be modified.

Comment: If values are being modified in a column, that is not a column you should be using as the key

Comment: So that's the issue, I can't use any of the columns in our dataset to create a unique key that never changes because they could all potentially be modified, so I want to create a key when the record is created. so the first row ever would be assigned a key of 0, second record a key of 1, etc... increasing incrementally and never reused or modified.

Comment: Cant be done in powerquery. It has to be done at the source

Comment: so the source is an excel sheet, so I'm exploring options with VBA as well

Comment: Can not envision how that would work, myself, but good luck