# Coding a unique number column in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a spreadsheet that will allow my coworkers to enter their hours and what they have been working on. I set it up so they have the option of entering the data via a userform or directly onto the sheet. I can't make it too complicated for the users so it's a very simple fill and submit or use the list boxes from validation to fill in the data on the sheet. However, I now need a code that will automatically enter a unique value key that will not change with additional entries or when an entry is deleted.
My plan is to create a query in a different workbook that will call each employees sheet and add a column where I can check off certain work. In order to do that though I need each entry to have a unique, never-changing key to create a self-referencing table in the query so my checks don't disappear each time it refreshes.

I've tried running various different codes for random number generators. But they keep refreshing all numbers or starting over when there's a new entry. There's not enough unique data in each entry to use a concat function either for a key.
Please please help! I have minimal coding knowledge and have been able to get the userform and such going mostly by copying and pasting codes I found, but now I'm totally stumped. Maybe it's not possible the way I would like.

[image: Worksheet]

Comment: why not using unique ID either the number of the row or the time when the record happened to the second(dd/mm/yy/hh:ss) like 14122023113622

Comment: Store an incrementing value in a cell (maybe on a hidden sheet) and get the next Id from there each time you need a new Id.  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77183250/478884

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see your existing code, but for your purposes, I would go with a guid.

```
Public Function GetGUID() As String 
    GetGUID = Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36) 
End Function
```

[borrowing from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990236/how-to-create-a-guid-in-excel)